# SharePoint and use of AD's wWWHomePage attribute

Tags: active-directory, sharepoint, attributes

While looking at the wWWHomePage attribute in Active Directory, a web search found some questions on lousier Q&A sites, that indicate that SharePoint will populate the wWWHomePage attribute on a user in AD with their SharePoint site.

The specific question I found was how to turn this off?  There was no answer there, so I would be curious to know how to turn it off.

But more importantly, what affect would there be to SharePoint if we turned this off?

We actually are planning on syncing in other data from another source into that attribute.  How would that affect SharePoint, if at all?

Should the answer be that it matters, I will later ask a question if the attribute has any funny syntax requirements as I was informed that in the past the people I am working with have had problems with some values in the field, even though the schema def seems to say it is just a 2K long single valued Unicode string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not entirely the complete answer, it is useful to know that while `wWWHomePage` is a single valued attribute, extra values are meant to overflow into `url` which is multivalued.

(We have an Identity Management project where single valued phone info in the source directory and LDAP accessible directory are mapped to the primary single valued phone attribute, and the rest overflow into the otherXXXX attributes.  (Thus there is `pager` and the overflow attribute `otherPager` and so on for the various phone attributes).)

So we will overflow multiple values from our source directory into `url` and leave one value in `wWWHomePage` which should obviate any Sharepoint potential issues.